# How do you write a grammar rule which leaves off a trailing character?

Tags: parsing, grammar

I am trying to basically say "match either some letters or a new line character, **except ignore the last new line character**". How can I do this with a regex? Or if not a regex, how can I do this with a grammar rule more formally (such as with BNF grammar syntax)?

If `a` and `b` are letters, and `c` is the new line, then I try a regex like `/abc+[^c]/`, but that isn't quite correct, it will only match `abcccccb` for example, not ignoring the last `c`.

I try with a more DSL approach:

```
rule match-multiline-string
  match multiple
    match or
      match letters
      match line-break
```

That will match trailing newlines though, whereas I want to only match everything up to the last new line. So then I try:

```
rule match-multiline-string
  match multiple
    match or
      match letters
      match line-break
  match line-break
    consume false
```

That seems like it will get it, but it would be tricky to implement. How do grammars typically handle this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In (f)lex you would do this with the [trailing context operator](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html#index-trailing-context_002c-in-patterns), using a rule like:

```
[[:alpha:]\n]+/\n        { yylval = strdup(yytext); return ML_STRING; }
```

(In (f)lex, the `$` operator is *exactly* the same as `/\n`, so I would normally write that particular rule as `[[:alpha:]\n]+$`. But that seemed a bit harder to understand.)

I don't know if that is really what you're looking for, since I suppose that you are not actually using (f)lex. But the same principle should work fine with any regular-expression-based scanner. Trailing context is implemented by matching as though the `/` wasn't there (so that the actual regular expression matched is `[[:alpha:]\n]+\n`) and then backing up the length of the trailing context before returning. That means that the maximal munch rule (if more than one regular expression matches, take the first rule in the file which matches the longest prefix) is interpreted as though the trailing context were part of the pattern. That's often convenient, even though it may seem counter-intuitive.

It's slightly more complicated if the trailing context has a variable length, but that's not really relevant here. Just in case, though, the actual algorithm used is to record the match position every time the DFA executes a transition from a state before the `/` to a state after the `/`; at the end, the scanner backs up to the last recorded match position. This is similar to the way the scanner implements maximal munch, which is to record the last match position every time an accepting state is reached.